# How can I control a PostgreSQL function is running in a long period of time

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

A program which I developed is using postgresql. That program is running a plpgsql function it is taking so long time(hours or days). I want to be sure that function is running during that long time.

How can I know that? I don't want to use "raise notice" in a loop in function because that will extend running time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see if it's *running* by examining `pg_stat_activity` for the process. However, this won't tell you if the function is *progressing*.

You can check to see whether that backend is blocked on any locks by joining `pg_stat_activity` against `pg_locks` to see if there are any open (`granted = False`) locks for that table. Again, this won't tell you if it's progressing, just that if it isn't it's not stuck on a lock.

If you want to monitor a function's progress you will need to emit log messages or use one of the other hacks for monitoring progress. You can (ab)use `NOTIFY` with payload to `LISTEN` for progress messages. Alternately, you could create a sequence that you call `nextval` on each time you process an item in your procedure; you can then `SELECT * FROM the_sequence_name;` in another transaction to see the approximate progress.

In general I'd recommend setting `client_min_messages` to `notice` or above then `RAISE LOG` so you record messages that appear only in the logs, without being sent to the client. To reduce overhead, keep a counter and log every 100 or 1000 or whatever iterations of your loop so you only log occasionally. There's a cost to updating the counter, for sure, but it's pretty low compared to the cost of a big, slow PL/PgSQL procedure like this.

Comment: How can I use NOTIFY command if in [Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html) it is said that any notifications are NOT delivered until transaction ends (i.e. until function completes)?